# Find failed with JPA in playframework

Tags: playframework

I'm using JPA in PlayFramwork.

I have a class Page with a field of HashSet

```
Set<PageStatus> pageStatus= new HashSet<PageStatus>();
```

I want to find Page with `Page.find("pageStatus like ?", status).fetch()` and it failed with exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [LATEST] was not matching type [java.util.Set]
```

status is a HashSet with these code

```
Set<PageStatus> statuses = new HashSet<PageStatus>();
statuses.add(PageStatus.LATEST);
```

Any suggestion? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a Set as an argument for a like clause. A like needs a string as the parameter. The only clause that can work with Set is the `in` clause

Comment: I tried in clause and failed as well. .find("pageStatus in ?", statuses)

Comment: in my case it works when writing find("from Page page where page.pageStatus in (?1)", pageStatus).fetch(); and with pageStatus behing a list. But like and in does not have the same meaning, be sure the request you write do what you want

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to filter by an M - N relation. That is, you have in one side a Set A and in the other a second Set B.

1. `IN` won't work as it's used to determine that a single element is inside a collection of elements. Like: *element x is in the given {array, list, set} z*. In your scenario you have 2 sets, this won't work.
2. `Like` compares Strings directly. For example, a String A is similar to a String B. You have two sets, it won't work either.

From your example, you want to filter by an element inside a Set of your entity. Try this:

```
PageStatus statuses = PageStatus.LATEST;
Page.find("(?1) in pageStatus", statuses).fetch()
```

If you want to filter by multiple elements, you'll have to concatenate the filters with `or`.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work neither...Is that a problem I annotate this filed  with @ElementCollection?